# How to run pyspark docker application using spark-submit from the command line?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, pyspark, spark-submit

I am trying to run the pyspark docker application using spark-submit from the command line.

The application script are available in the same directory where the spark-submit is invoked..

Below is the code:

```
user@ubuntu$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/
user@ubuntu$ ls
test_spark.py

## Attempt 1
user@ubuntu$ docker run --rm -it --link master:master htc/spark-submit spark-submit --master spark://172.17.0.1:7077 /home/ubuntu/test_spark.py 

## Attempt2
user@ubuntu$ docker run --rm -it --link master:master htc/spark-submit spark-submit --master spark://172.17.0.1:7077 test_spark.py
```

But the script throw the error says 'no such file' in above both cases

Would like to know how spark application can run from the same directory?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't u have the file inside docker if u are trying to run it in the container ???

Comment: Thanks @Inder for the replay.. so how i supposed to call the script if i have saved inside the htc/spark-submit container in this case?

Comment: You can specify that in the `ENTRYPOINT`, more on the same is accessible on the link attaced
https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/#:~:text=ENTRYPOINT%20instruction%20allows%20you%20to,runs%20with%20command%20line%20parameters.